# properties of the Mandelbrot set and complex dynamical system

Tags: complex-dynamics

I want to learn some knowledge about complex dynamical system, especially about the properties of Mandelbrot set, are there any literatures about this topics?

Answer (score 2):

Milnor's book (available here : https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201272) is a good reference. Note that you will need a solid knowledge of complex analysis as a prerequisite.

Comment: Yeah, that is the book I am reading now, I find it is interesting, I will go on reading this one, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- *The Science of Fractal Images* chapter 4 and appendix D 
  H-O. Peitgen et al (eds.) 
  https://archive.org/details/scienceoffractal0000unse_1987
- interactive demonstrations in *Mandel* software 
  Wolf Jung 
  http://mndynamics.com/indexp.html
- *Dynamics in one complex variable* 
  John W. Milnor 
  https://abel.math.harvard.edu/archive/118r_spring_05/docs/milnor.pdf
- *Exploring the Mandelbrot set. The Orsay Notes* 
  Adrien Douady, John H. Hubbard 
  [https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/OrsayEnglish.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehubbard/OrsayEnglish.pdf)
- *Internal addresses in the Mandelbrot set and Galois groups of polynomials* 
  Dierk Schleicher 
  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411238
- various preprints on arXiv by the above and others

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly recommendation! You give me a lot of help,thanks again!